# Xamarin.Forms - Push notification for iOS and Android

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, xamarin.forms

Hell. I'm just write my first mobile app and I use XamarinForms

So I try understand to understand how work push notification here....and i'm a little bit confused

So this is what I understand

For android I MUST(!) use google cloud messaging - right?
For iOS - I MUST(!) use Apple Apple Notification Push Service - right?

Now my question:
If I use xamarin forms - i write 1 code to 2 platfoms andoid/iOS - right??
so how i can write 1 code both for gcm and apple notif????

How I think - but not sure - I need write interface in my PCL and then write separate implementation in each platform??
This is write way??

Why I need Push notifications?

I have app and when admin attach task to user - he will get notification about he has new task.

Or when user use app - real time get new data - new task

So if you can give me a tips - thank you.

Sorry for my English grammar)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to this plugin https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification in the description you can find the proper setup for each platform.
Also keep in mind that even if you're using Xamarin.Forms you will need to know how works push notifications on each platform.

Android. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/
iOS. https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

is you have any specific question about it pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

Azure has "push notification hub" that plugs into both iOS and Google
Try that. Once youve set it up it will push stuff to google and to apple.